# Conflicting imports

Tags: purescript

I can run this code in Haskell

```
module Foo where
test = 1

module Bar where
test = 2

module Main where
import Foo
import Bar
main = print "test"
```

But PureScript compiler return an error

> Conflicting imports for test from modules Bar and Foo

Is this a bug?

Comment: I think this is by design, but you might get a more detailed response if you post this on the compiler issues list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a bug, but it will be changed.

https://github.com/purescript/purescript/issues/1497